# how to change ispconfig clamav log file location

Tags: clamav

On ispconfig 3 web interface, log files section under Monitor

There are several log files, one of them is Mail Log and other is ClamAV Log.

Unfortunately ClamAV log points to same file as Mail Log which is /var/log/maillog

I want to change the link of ClamAV Log to point another log file that I'll create to display daily scan results. That log file is at /var/log/clamav/manual_clamscan.log

How can I do this hyperlink change?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vim /usr/local/ispconfig/server/lib/classes/monitor_tools.inc.php
```

Line 1725 for redhat it checks if `/var/log/clamav/clamd.log` exists

```
case 'log_clamav':
[...]
    if ($dist == 'redhat') {
          $logfile = (is_file('/var/log/clamav/clamd.log') ? '/var/log/clamav/clamd.log' : '/var/log/maillog');
    }
[...]
```

It does not exist at all so I touched the file and pointed clam cron job to this log file. This also works for other log file programmed there in this php file.

### problem solved